# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' python select query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a query. My query returns the result that i want as a dictionary. I use python 3.7 and mysql. Im on ubuntu 18
Like:

```
[{'community_string': 'public'}, {'community_string': 'private'}]
```

I want to use only public and private as a string. For doing it, i wrote my code like that:

```
query= "SELECT community_string FROM nat_snmp_string WHERE status ='enable'"
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute(query)
com_str = cursor.fetchall()
com_str_string = com_str.values()
cmnyt_str = json.dumps(list(com_str))
print(cmnyt_str)  
cmd_line = cmnyt_str.replace(':','')
cmd_line = cmd_line.replace('"','')
cmd_line = cmd_line.replace(']','')
cmd_line = cmd_line.replace('[','')
```

but it gives me **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'** error.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It appears that `cursor.fetchall()` is returning a list, and not a dictionnary.

Comment: should I use cursor.fethone() ? 
Im a newbie, sorry for it. In db, i may have more than 2 values because of that i use fetchall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear, what do you want to do.
Do you want to get the value of "community_string"?

```
for r in cursor.fetchall():
   print(r['community_string'])
```

I don't understand what do you do with json and string replace operations...

Comment: Yes i want to get the value of community string. I tried but it gives error ---> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from